# How do I distinguish a handwritten long "s"(ſ) and a lowercase "f"?

Tags: palaeography

The [long s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)(ſ) is often confused with the lower case [f](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F).

Because the use of the long s died out in the early 19th century, few are familiar with it.

It leads to [many](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86774/what-animal-is-a-weefil) [confusions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37982/use-of-f-instead-of-s-in-historic-printed-english-documents). Now, in printed text, they are easy to tell apart-- the long s has no nub. In handwritten texts (such as early birth records), the two seem indistinguishable to me.

Is there any way to tell the two apart in handwritten texts?

Comment: Interesting possible overlap here between us and english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, but this also could apply to any language using a Latin Alphabet (including English). However, this question is focusing on the handwritten forms, whereas ELU SE does not.

Comment: Was just struck by the fact that the confusions you referred to were both on another stackexchange site (and both refer to printed documents)

Comment: While linking to Wikipedia was a good idea, I do think it would have been nice to see some interesting graphic examples be provided as part of this question.

Comment: Well, take the last letter of the first numbered line here for example. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2077/56 Bgwiehle calls it an "s", but it could be "Lauf". Funny (no pun intended).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The U.S.A. [Bill of Rights](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Bill_of_Rights_Pg1of1_AC.jpg) is a good example for study. We know exactly in what time frame and context it was written. At the top, we have the long S in

> Congreſs of the United States

and the title is boldface italics (so to speak). This long-S does have a cross stroke, but it's not clear from the image whether that's a background line or actually is a cross stroke.

If you scan down through the document, you'll see many examples of double f, and near by examples of long-S-short-s. For example,

> be subject for the same offence *(Article 7 line 2)*

is directly above

> without due proceſs of law. *(Article 7 line 3)*

In this specific document, there is a difference between the two letters. Look at the direction of the lower part of the letter (clockwise vs. counter-clockwise). For a single isolated lower-case F, the descender is always formed counter-clockwise. For a long S, the descender is always formed clockwise. However, in the case of double-F, the first F's descender is clockwise, and the second F's descender is counter-clockwise.

I have never seen that distinction "officially" explained, but I have noticed it in other early 19th century American (USA) handwriting.

I *think* I have only seen the long-S as the first letter of a double-S combination. But I've only looked at USA handwriting, 1680-1880. Hopefully these minor distinctions will help you recognize the difference more easily!

Answer (score 8):

According to [The National Archives](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/palaeography/where_to_start.htm):

> Don't get long s and f mixed up. The 'f' will have a cross stroke, even if it's hardly noticeable, and the context will make it clear whether it is a long 's' or an 'f'. Writers would often use both long and short 's', sometimes even in the same word.

Comment: The long s sometimes has a nub at the middle, and so it can appear even more like an elaborate lower case "f." (Even more difficult when talking about script.) See Wikipedia's entry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s

Comment: @GeneJ, I thought the long s only has a nub in the middle in typeface not in handwriting.

Answer (score 5):

1. If the sample is large enough, you can identify all the occurrences of f and long s, thereby distinguishing the writers hand.
2. If f and long s are almost identical, usually the word in question can be defined through trial and error. People and place names are most difficult.
3. German-Americans continued using long s into the early 20th century. An ancestor of mine, named Elisabetha, was recorded in a book of tombstone inscriptions as "Chalberna". I didn't learn her true name until I visited the grave, and saw the readers had misinterpreted the gothic script and long s.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This hypothesis is based on a very limited dataset (one Welsh parish register circa 1800) but may be worth further testing.

It appears that a "long s" was not used when it would be the last letter of the word. If you could be certain that any such letters were **f**, then you have a good basis for comparison of individual writing styles.